# how to get id to change in an if else statement in a function inside a function

Tags: javascript

I have a function that takes each URL in an api, where when adding that as an endpoint it gives me different values of that object. [first result from more simple url](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rKDDa.png) [results from the endpoint added to the ULR](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X7DIv.png). I have this code where the user inputs a spell name, the code turns it into an index and an if else loop checks if the spell has certain properties and defines a variable to the either damage type, heal, or spell school. That just defines the background image.

```
async function getData(){
    let thing = DOMSelectors.itemname.value.toLowerCase();
    thing = thing.replaceAll(' ','-')
    let URL = `https://www.dnd5eapi.co/api/spells/${thing}`; 
    console.log(URL)
    try {
        const response = await fetch(URL);
        console.log(response);
    if (response.status !=200){
        throw new Error(response.statusText);
    }
    const data = await response.json(); 
    let id = ""
    if(data.hasOwnProperty("damage")){
        id = data.damage.damage_type.index
    }else if(data.hasOwnProperty("heal_at_slot_level")){
        id= "heal"
    }else{
        id=data.school.index
    }
    console.log(data.name, id);
   DOMSelectors.parent2.insertAdjacentHTML(
        "afterbegin",
        `<div class='card' id=${id}>
        <h2 id="name" class="name">${data.name}</h2>
        <h3 id="price" class="name">${data.desc}</h3>
        <button class="btn">REMOVE</button>
        </div>`
    )
    } catch (error){
       alert("Enter a valid spell")
    }
}
```

I have another function that just makes a catalouge and creates a card for each spell on the original URL. Im trying to do the same if else statement to make the backgrounds for each card but it wont change the variable.

```
let URL2 = `https://www.dnd5eapi.co/api/spells/`; 
async function populate(){
    console.log(URL2)
    const response = await fetch(URL2);
    const data = await response.json();
    try {
        console.log(response);
    if (response.status !=200){
        throw new Error(response.statusText);
    }
    data.results.forEach((link)=> thing(link.url));
    let id ="ok"
   async function thing(x){
        let url = "https://www.dnd5eapi.co"+x;
        const response2 = await fetch(url);
        const data2 = await response2.json();
        if(data2.hasOwnProperty("damage")){
           id="wow"
        }else if(data2.hasOwnProperty("heal_at_slot_level")){
            id= "heal"
        }else{
            id="pow!"
        }}
    data.results.forEach(element => DOMSelectors.parent1.insertAdjacentHTML(
        "beforeend",
        `<div class='catalouges' id="${id}">
        <h2 id="asdf" class="title">${element.name}</h2>
        </div>`
    ));
}
catch (error){alert("Enter a valid spell")}}
```

wow heal and pow are just placeholders

I tried to see if the if else was actually checking for each property of each spell, and it does. But I cant just make it change the variable.

Comment: Your code would be more readable if you didn't name things "thing".

Comment: Your `thing` function is asynchronous, as it `await`s the api call. It *does* change the `id` variable, but only *after* `populate` has inserted the html with the empty id.

Comment: Move the `let id` declaration and the `parent1.insertAdjacentHTML(…)` inside your `thing` function, after the if/else statements, to fix this. Or alternatively just call `getData` instead of `thing` (passing the thing and the parent element as paremeters).